# Google Chrome Device Emulator mode select box error

Tags: google-chrome

When I select select box in Google Chrome in Device Mode(iPad), the list is shown in black and far from the select box. How can I fix this; My Google Chrome version is 53.0.2785.116 64 bit running on Window 10 - 64bit.
[image: Google Chrome error when selecting select box]

UPDATE:
It works as expected in Google Chrome Normal mode, Firefox and IE

The code I tested:

```
<html>
<body>
<select>
    <option>abcdefg</option>
    <option>abcdefg</option>
    <option>abcdefg</option>
    <option>abcdefg</option>
    <option>abcdefg</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this happen with other browsers aswell? Or what kind of code are you using?

Comment: Did you try your site on an actual iPad?  Maybe the website is made incorrectly.

Comment: @Dylan Rz: No, normal mode of chrome working as expected, Firefox and IE no problem.

Comment: @Nelson: On real device working as expected.

Comment: Does this also happen when you just browse on google chrome? if not than its just the emulator not working correctly.

Comment: @DylanRz: Only google chrome emulator not working correctly.